# Intersect Statement Fails When Column is Empty

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble with part of a macro which opens a file and reformats the contents. Part of the code (below) reformats a column using "For Each ___ in Intersect", but if the column is blank, the macro crashes.

```
For Each Cel In Intersect(NewWs.Range("i3:i65536"), NewWs.UsedRange).Cells
    If Cel = "" Then
    Cel.Value = "-"
    End If
```

What is the most direct way to prevent it from crashing and just move on if the column is empty? If more information is needed please let me know.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Intersect(NewWs.Range("i3:i65536"), NewWs.UsedRange)
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    For Each Cel In r.Cells
        If Cel = "" Then
            Cel.Value = "-"
        End If
    Next Cel
End If
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks so much. Works like a charm. Do you know how I indicate this is a correct answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you are not so concerned with zero length strings returned by formulas as you are with truly blank cells. If this is the case, you can avoid your loop and backfill the blank cells with the hyphen character by identifying the blank cells with `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`.

```
Dim mt As Range
Set mt = Intersect(NewWs.Range("i3:i65536"), NewWs.UsedRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
If Not mt Is Nothing Then _
    mt = Chr(45) 'hyphen character
```

This will be much quicker than cycling through the cells and testing each one for a lack of a value. The bonus is that if there are no blank cells, the whole operation is dicarded and you can get on to the next operation. However, if you have zero length strings returned by formulas (e.g. "") then this is not going to identify them as they are not truly blank cells. And of course, the formulas could have returned the hyphen in the first place.